# how to assess a periodical signal?

Tags: light

After folding a light curve, we may  get some kind of shape.
How to tell whether there is a real periodical signal quantifiably?

The fluctuation may be small, and the folded shape may not be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You have it the wrong way around. You have to establish a periodicity before doing the folding.

There are various ways to do this, but the most frequently (pun intended) used is the [Lomb-Scargle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_spectral_analysis#The_Lomb.E2.80.93Scargle_periodogram) periodogram.

Start with a datset consisting of a set of points $(t_i, m_i\pm \sigma_i )$, where $t_i$ are times of observation and $m_i$ and $\sigma_i$ are the fluxes and their uncertainties at those times.

You then calculate an array of chi-squared statistics, by fitting a mean level $\bar{m}$ and sinusoidal functions over a range of discrete frequencies $\omega$. The aim is to *maximise* the statistic
$$p(\omega) = \frac{\chi^2_{0} - \chi^2(\omega)}{\chi^2_{0}},$$
where 
$$\chi^{2}_{0} = \sum (m_i - \bar{m})^2/\sigma_i^{2}$$ and 
$$\chi^{2}(\omega) = \sum  (y_i - \bar{m})^2/\sigma_i^{2},$$ with $y_i = A\sin(\omega t_i + \phi) + A_0$, where $A$, $A_0$ and $\phi$ are free parameters that are optimised for each frequency (i.e. you find the minimum possible $\chi^2(\omega)$ at each frequency).

Once a period is obtained from a peak in the power spectrum, $p_{best}$, *then* it must be established whether this peak is "real" or significant.

Theoretically, the probability that $p>p_{best}$ is $(1-p_{best})^{(N-3)/2}$ for $N$ independent measurements (see [Cumming, Marcy & Butler 1999](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9906466)). This is the "false alarm probability" - the chance that you would get $p>p_{best}$ from random, aperiodic data with those uncertainties.

However, real data has correlated noise and the points are not independent. So what you do instead (see [Collier Cameron et al. 2009](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0189)) is shuffle all the times of the data points (i.e. randomly reallocate the times of each observation) and go through the process again. Do this a squillion times with different random reallocations and see how many times you end up with $p>p_{best}$. This gives you some idea about how confident you can be that your detected periodic signal is real. This is called a "bootstrap Monte-Carlo method".

There are other ways to do this; my answer is not complete; but it's the one I'm familiar with.

Comment: it is said that we can calculate the dispersion and chi2 directly?

Comment: @questionhang I don't understand your follow-up question. I have given you a prescription to find the most likely period from a set of data $t_i, m_i\pm \sigma_i$, and then assess how confident you can be that the periodic signal did not arise by chance.

Comment: my point is how to assess the significance of a periodical signal. Is there a more popular way than CC's?

Comment: @questionhang This is how (or minor variants thereof) periodic signals are found and their significance assessed in Kepler, SuperWASP, HATnet and the various Doppler shift surveys for exoplanets.

Comment: I remember there is a method which can give significance level directly. Let me search for that first.